# Cucumber snapshot when scenario fails - does not work

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I currently have the following implementation for snapshots when scenarios fails -

```
@After("@destroy")
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws Throwable {
    try {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {

            final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driverC).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

            /*
             * final File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)
             * driverC).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
             * FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(screenshot, new
             * File("/home/ninad/eclipse-workspace/Reports/html"));
             */

        }
    } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
        System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
    } finally {
        driverC.close();
    }

}
```

These are my scenarios -

```
Scenario: Filter Airline with Dropdowns
Given element with id "at-offloadsreceived" is displayed 
When I select option "string:OMA" from dropdown "at-usrAirlineDropDown" 
And I click element with id "at-filterBtn" 
Then element with id "at-hdr-tailsign" is displayed
And element with id "at-link-tailsign-20" is displayed 



@destroy 
Scenario: Navigate to Home and Shutdown 
Given I am on the "/#/ted/home" page 
Then element with id "landing_header" is displayed
```

I have seen different issues:

1. No Snapshots are ever taken and then embedded.
2. If the error occurs on the scenario that has the @destroy tag, the snapshot will be taken, but on the previous scenario, if there is an error, no snapshot will be taken.
3. Embedding tends to not work, only saving in another location (commented out code) works.
4. Multiple scenarios with errors, there will be no snapshot for all of them. Just one snapshot will be produced.

Any help will be much appreciated. FYI - I am new to this, so step-by-step instructions are the best! :)

Comment: The after hook has a 'destroy' tag so will only be called with scenarios having that tag.

Comment: When I put the snapshot code in an @After before the @After("@destroy"), i get the following error - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Comment: Why do you have 2 After hooks?

Comment: One to take snapshots after failed scenarios, and one to close the browser when the feature file is over. Actually, this method finally worked after upgrading my chromedriver for the above error. Thanks!